# SNMPv3 do not work in zabbix

Tags: zabbix, system-monitoring, net-snmp, snmpv3

If I run snmpwalk on the same machine of zabbix server I can collect data with SNMPv3

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u Usnmp -l AuthNoPriv -a MD5 -A 'AuthPass' 10.x.x.x .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (61650508) 7 days, 3:15:05.08
```

But in Zabbix Server I can't.

Zabbix do not give me data, queue always empty for SNMPv3 agent, error message in front end no even error message in the log.

My zabbix config:

```
Type: SNMPv3 agent
Key: SysUptime
Host interface: 10.x.x.x:161
SNMP OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
Security name: {$SNMP_SECNAME}
Security level: authNoPriv
Authentication protocol: MD5
Authentication passphrase: {$SNMP_AUTH}
```

Detail of "no error message in the front end" 
[image: NO_Error_Message]

Zabbix do not collect data.
[image: No data received]

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Zabbix to get the snmp traps ? It's not working out of the box. If you didn't, [check the Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/snmptrap)